# How to develop DNS for instances and that DNS names are not accesed outside Amazon Web Services cloud?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

I have many instances in my amazon web service cloud now i want to develop DNS for server and all instances will have elastic IP. Now i want to do something by which DNS cannot be acceded outside i.e. want to develop DNS only for internal instances.

Comment: Belongs on ServerFault.com (which oddly no longer appears in the off-topic selection).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you want to run DNS on EC2 or outside the network?  Remember EC2 instances with an elastic IP address have an "internal" (natted) IP address.  Do you want DNS to return the internal IP addresses or the elastic (public) IP addresses?

I think the easy solution is this.  On whatever machine or instance you run the DNS server on, put up a firewall on that box such that only AWS addresses (e.g. in the 107.*.*.* and 50.*.*.* range) are permitted. Or restricted to just your instance/elastic IP addresses. Configure the IP address of this DNS server to be the primary DNS server for your other instances.

Another easy solution is to run all your instances on a VPC.  All the instances that need to be accessed from the public can still have elastic IP addresses.  Then run a DNS server on another instance on this VPC - but without an elastic IP address. This means your DNS server would be at 10.0.0.3 or something. That IP address won't be accessible to the outside world, but is internally reachable by machines within the VPC. I'm not sure of the network topology between your instances are, but if they only need DNS to communicate between each other, then you could even have a public DNS server that returns the 10.x.y.z addresses for instances on the VPC.

Comment: I want DNS for my inter server communication and all instances will have elastic IP. Server can be identified by ip for outside enviroment and for internal enviroment DNS will be there.